# How to create this list view

Tags: list, list-view

[image: itemized list view]

Hello! I am new to sharepoint and I need to make my list look like the one in the photo I attached. How do I do that? I use SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Does your list have the correct columns setup, or are you trying to set this up as well?

Comment: It has the correct columns setup. Thanks it's done :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow below steps:

- Navigate to the list and Open it
- Go to List tab in ribbon
- Click on List Settings
- Go To Views section
- Click on the view you want to modify
- Go to Group By section and expand it
- Select the specific column name you want to use to group by under "First group by the column:" section
- If you want to do another level of group by you can select the column in another dropdown
- Click OK
- Navigate to the view and you have got the expected view

For explanation with screenshots refer [this article](http://mscerts.programming4.us/sharepoint/SharePoint%202010%20%20%20Specify%20How%20Items%20in%20a%20View%20Are%20Grouped.aspx)

**Note** :

Grouping is available only for standard and Gantt view types.

Answer (score 0):

Please create new list view and select group by column as status from options.